# List and kill multiple processes in PowerShell having same username

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have 4-5 process (like java.exe, javaw.exe etc) having username "OWNER"(suppose). Below is the script that filters the java.exe process and kills it if it belongs to "OWNER". I need your help to modify this so that any process related to "OWNER" would be killed if found.

Comment: @4c74356b41 formatting here means?

Comment: Let me know if formatting looks ok or not..

Comment: `@{}gwmi win32_process` - this doesn't look right

Comment: It's working on prod boxes from past 2 years without any issue for java.exe . I want to add feature for more process in this script, need help for that.

Comment: it cannot possibly work, its a typo or a mistake, just try it

Comment: Ok. I will look into it. But any help to add more process apart from java having same username to kill in same script  .. how to go for that ..

Answer (score 5):

Just do it with `Get-Process`:

```
get-process -IncludeUserName | where username -like $username | stop-process
```

Basically your whole script can be replaced with this line

Comment: V3 don't have includeusername

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Process` with `-IncludeUsername` switch is only available in WMF 5.0.

WMI is the option here.

You could probably terminate the process just by checking the owner equals to the corresponding user.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process | Where-Object -FilterScript { 
$_.GetOwner.User -eq "$Owner" } | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Terminate
```

Edit: The above code is a one liner, you could save the out put of `Get-WmiObject` in a variable and for `foreach` through the collection to print the process `id` and call the `terminate()` method instead of using `Invoke-WmiMethod`.

Note:This code is not tested

Comment: This seems to be good idea . Although I first want to print the process ID and want to kill that.. How to do that with the command you typed ..

Comment: You will not get a ready made script for your task from StackOverflow, I have edited the Answer by giving you max hint.

Comment: In the actual script I pasted I want that to be used as some dependency on that section . Hope you got the point . I will try to club all the help you guys provided .